# How to always show the menu in GRUB2?

Tags: grub2

Installing Ubuntu 10.10 I get the GRUB2 boot manager. By default is does instant booting of the first entry, i.e. you have to hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while booting when you want to enter the menu.

How can I disable this behavior? I mean, how can I configure GRUB2 such that it always displays its menu and uses perhaps a timeout of 5 seconds for the first entry?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the extremely detailed and well-written [Wiki entry for Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202). The setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` should be what you are looking for. But pay attention to the instructions on how to change settings.

Comment: Yes, setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=` (yes, this a newline after the equal sign) and running `update-grub` disables instant booting. The grub menu is then displayed for `GRUB_TIMEOUT` seconds. IMHO this is a little bit unintuitive. The wiki entry is very detailed indeed - but the `/etc/default/grub` file should incorporate some of its details regarding the complex timeout logic as comments.

Comment: @maxschlepzig +1 for the understatement *a little bit unintuitive*

Answer (score 1):

[Using ZORIN]

I also found editing the `GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480` settings fixed the problem. However, first, I had to add the `grub-customizer`.

Optional, if step 1 doesn't work

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

1. `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. Find Grub Customizer in the GUI (for me it's in System>Administration>..., but for some it is fund under Applications>System Tools>..)
4. Open Grub Customizer and select Preferences > Advanced
5. Select `GRUB_gfxmode (640X480)` - if it is already selected, deselect it, reboot, and select it again.
6. Cross your fingers and reboot!

I have no idea why this worked for me, but it worked on both of my computers, so hopefully it will work for you too!